# Dart - How to serve gzip-encoded html page

Tags: dart

I'm trying to gzip a .html file and then pipe it to `HttpResponse`.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  File f = new File('some_template.html');
  HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080)
    .then((HttpServer server) {
      server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
        HttpResponse response = request.response;
        f.openRead()
          .transform(GZIP.encoder)
          .pipe(response);
      });
    });
}
```

No error, but instead of serving the html page, the browser downloads the compressed html page. Care to give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HttpServer automatically compresses data as GZIP if the client accepts zipped data and some other requirements are fulfilled (see below). Even if it didn't, you couldn't just zip the data and expect the browser to understand it. The browser expects pure text (HTML) and would probably just download the binary data to disk. You would also need to set the header's content-encoding.

`dart:io` automatically compresses the data *except* in the following cases:

- `Content-Length` is set: the `Content-Length` header must be the length *after* GZIP, and `dart:io` can't therefore compress the data,
- the client doesn't accept it (sent in `Accept-Encoding`), or
- the `Content-Encoding` header is already set by the developer.

Some relevant sections of Dart's http implementation:

```dart
// _writeHeaders (http_impl.dart):
if (acceptEncodings != null &&
    acceptEncodings
        .expand((list) => list.split(","))
        .any((encoding) => encoding.trim().toLowerCase() == "gzip") &&
    contentEncoding == null) {
  headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
  _asGZip = true;
}

// _addStream (same file):
if (_asGZip) {
  stream = stream.transform(GZIP.encoder);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned above, the automatic compression cannot be used if setting the `Content-Length` header. If you want to set the `Content-Length` header it must be the content length *after* compression.

The following code illustrates how to serve an already compressed resource using the content length of the compressed data.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

var page =
r'''
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!!!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!!!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
''';

void requestHandler(HttpRequest request) {
  List<int> compressed = GZIP.encode(UTF8.encode(page));
  request.response
    ..headers.contentType = ContentType.HTML
    ..headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, 'gzip')
    ..headers.contentLength = compressed.length
    ..add(compressed)
    ..close();
}

main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 8080);
  server.autoCompress = true;
  server.defaultResponseHeaders.chunkedTransferEncoding = true;
  server.listen(requestHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In latest SDK, you have to enable [HttpServer.autoCompress](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpServer#id_autoCompress) and [HttpHeaders.chunkedTransferEncoding](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpHeaders#id_chunkedTransferEncoding).

Example,

```
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  HttpServer
  .bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 8080)
  .then((server) {
    server.autoCompress = true;
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      request.response.write('Hello, world!');
      request.response.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Here are response headers:

```
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
transfer-encoding:chunked
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

> Notice that chunckedTransferEncoding is set automatically if it is HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Yes, but how exactly is it done? `server.autoCompress = true; server.defaultResponseHeaders.chunkedTransferEncoding = true;` makes my `HttpRequest` calls report `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

Comment: Technically you don't have to set chunkedTransferEncoding, since it is set automatically when HTTP 1.1 was detected. You can check the source code of Dart SDK directly.

Comment: Had removed that, eliminated that error, but doesn't seem like it's compressed according to Network tab and Page Insights report. Confirmed this works in 1.9.3+?

Comment: Yes, it is what we did in [Quire](https://quire.io). I added a simple example above. Hope it helps.

Comment: My issue was code was setting content-length elsewhere, as Søren mentions in his answer.